# how to remove the extra commas in numbers in csv file after converting from excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a next code for converting excel file to csv file:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application reportExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks reportBooks = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook reportBook = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets reportSheets = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet reportSheet = null;
try
{
    reportBooks = reportExcel.Workbooks;
    reportBook = reportBooks.Open(excelFilePath);
    reportSheets = reportBook.Sheets;
    reportSheet = reportSheets.get_Item(1);
    if (File.Exists(csvtempFile))
    {
        File.Delete(csvtempFile);
    }
    reportBook.SaveAs(csvtempFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false);
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
finally
{
    ...
}
```

I get next text in csv file:

```
...
"Some strings","309,145","4,964,398",,"1,194,780",,
...
```

As you see numbers contain an extra comma. Please tell me how to remove extra comma for getting next value:

```
"Some strings","309,145","4964,398",,"1194,780",,
```

Comment: You mean you want `,"309145","4964398",,"1194780",,` instead?

Comment: *Which* extra commas? The ones indicating thousands, or the ones indicating empty columns?

Comment: I wrote: "As you see numbers contain an extra comma", so: The ones indicating thousands.

Comment: This is a reason you should try to *not* implement your own CSV parser. While the format is deceptively simple, it has lots of corner cases and exceptions like the one you just found. There are many libraries, if you just search a little, which handles these cases very well. There's also another problem with CSV files: No meta-data. Unless there's a formal specification of what each field means, you can tell what kind of data is in the fields.

Comment: So my advice to you is: Don't make your own parser, and use a converter for the contained data that can handle the format it's in (like numbers with commas as thousands-separator).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [Set data type like number, text and date in excel column using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827709/set-data-type-like-number-text-and-date-in-excel-column-using-microsoft-office)

You can check column type, set a range on each one you want to change and then set the number format before exporting it.

I know it is not pretty, but might work if you don't find something prettier.